При попытке вызова асинхронной функции (asyncio) через кнопку интерфейса TKinter вылезает ошибка Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
При запуске файла открывается окно интерфейса, написанное на TKInter+Async. При нажатии кнопки "START" создается loop основной программы, запускается метод main(). Алгоритм подключается к Binance по нескольким потокам веб-сокета, и начинается поиск и открытие сделок. На этой стадии всё прекрасно работает. НО: Как только я пытаюсь вызвать функцию on_close_orders() - выдает ошибку Timeout context manager should be used inside a task. Предполагаю, что это из-за того, что функция вызывается или находится вне контекста основной Loop, но не понимаю, что нужно сделать, чтобы её туда поместить. Пытался решить проблему вызовом функции через asyncio.create_taks(on_close_orders()), но результат аналогичный. Полный отчет по ошибке ниже:
Подскажите, как исправить этот код, чтобы функция нормально вызывалась по нажатию кнопки?
import asyncio
import threading
import time
import binance_folder
import indicators
from config import API_KEY, SECRET_KEY
import sys
import traceback
import datetime
from indicators import SuperTrend_numpy
import numpy as np

from async_tkinter_loop import async_handler, async_mainloop
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

async def btn_click_start():
    global main
    global btn_start
    btn_start.state(['disabled'])
    ws_main = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(main(),)).start()

async def btn_click_close():
    global client
    if client:
        await on_close_orders()

root = Tk()
root['bg'] = '#ffffff'
root.title('MCG ROBOT')
root.geometry('500x500')

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frame_input = Frame(root, bg='gray')
frame_input.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.02, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.95)
frame_control = Frame(root, bg='white')
frame_control.place(relx=0.39, rely=0.87, relwidth=0.59, relheight=0.1)
title = Label(frame_input, text='Входные параметры', bg='gray', font=40)
title.pack()
btn_start = ttk.Button(frame_control, text='START', command=async_handler(btn_click_start))
btn_start.pack()
btn_start.place(x=10, y=15)
btn_stop = ttk.Button(frame_control, text='STOP')
btn_stop.pack()
btn_stop.place(x=105, y=15)
btn_close = ttk.Button(frame_control, text='CLOSE ALL', command=async_handler(btn_click_close))
btn_close.pack()
btn_close.place(x=200, y=15)
loginInput = Entry(frame_input, bg='white')
loginInput.pack()
loginInput.place(x=10, y=15)
passField = Entry(frame_input, bg='white', show='*')
passField.pack()
passField.place(x=10, y=50)

async def on_close_orders():
    acc = await client.account()
    print('Пытаемся закрыть все открытые позиции')
    for i in acc['positions']:
        if float(i['positionAmt']) != 0.0:
            print(f'Нашли открытую позицию по {i["symbol"]}')
            try:
                if float(i['positionAmt']) > 0:
                    print('Определили, что ордер открыт в покупку')
                    print(f"price={float(i['notional']) * 1.01 / float(i['positionAmt'])}")
                    close = await client.new_order(symbol=i['symbol'], side='SELL', type='MARKET', timeInForce="GTC",
                                                reduceOnly=True, quantity=abs(float(i['positionAmt'])))

                    print(f"по монетке {i['symbol']} закрыли позицию")
                elif float(i['positionAmt']) < 0:
                    print('Определили, что ордер открыт в продажу')
                    close = await client.new_order(symbol=i['symbol'], side='BUY', type='MARKET', timeInForce="GTC",
                                                reduceOnly=True, quantity=abs(float(i['positionAmt'])))
                    print(f"по монетке {i['symbol']} закрыли позицию")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Позиция не закрыта по причине: ")
                print(e)

async def main():
    global client
    global all_symbols
    client = binance_folder.Futures(api_key=API_KEY, secret_key=SECRET_KEY, asynced=True, testnet=False)
    all_symbols = await client.load_symbols()
    while not all_symbols:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    await filter_symbols()
    await limited_historycal_klines_requests(symbols)
    await create_topics()
    asyncio.create_task(execute_order_pool())
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    async_mainloop(root)


>     Task exception was never retrieved
>     future: <Task finished name='Task-837' coro=<on_close_orders() done, defined at
> C:\PycharmProjects\python_robot_MCG\Pattern_bot_+TKinter.py:482>
> exception=RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used inside
> a task')>
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\PycharmProjects\python_robot_MCG\Pattern_bot_+TKinter.py",
> line 483, in on_close_orders
>         acc = await client.account()
>       File "C:\PycharmProjects\python_robot_MCG\binance_folder\client.py",
> line 88, in _request_async
>         async with getattr(self.session, method)(self.base_url + url, **kwargs) as response:
>       File "C:\PycharmProjects\python_robot_MCG\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py",
> line 1357, in __aenter__
>         self._resp: _RetType = await self._coro
>       File "C:\PycharmProjects\python_robot_MCG\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py",
> line 577, in _request
>         with timer:
>       File "C:\PycharmProjects\python_robot_MCG\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py",
> line 712, in __enter__
>         raise RuntimeError(
>     RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task


Избавьтесь от глобальных переменных в вашем коде

Попробуйте запускать main через asyncio.create_task() вместо отдельного треда.

@СергейШ Проблема при устранении глобальных переменных сохраняется - та же самая

@insolor, Огромное спасибо, всё сработало без ошибок!

Т.к. btn_click_start у вас уже асинхронная функция, то и main из нее имеет смысл запускать как асинхронный таск (через asyncio.create_task()), а не в отдельном потоке:
async def btn_click_start():
    btn_start.state(['disabled'])
    ws_main = asyncio.create_task(main())

Сообщение об ошибке прямо указывает, что нужен таск (подразумевается асинхронный таск). Теоретически можно было бы из main запускать код в таком таске, но проще сам main запускать через create_task, а не через создание потока. Отдельный поток может понадобиться, если используются какие-то блокирующие операции, но в данном случае ничего такого вроде бы нет.
Дополнительно могут быть какие-то неочевидные проблемы с тем, когда какие-то объекты создаются во вторичном потоке (тот же client), а используются в основном потоке.

В самом main вижу такую конструкцию:
asyncio.create_task(execute_order_pool())
while True:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

В данном случае это можно заменить на одну строку
await execute_order_pool()


Немного по поводу global: global в целом стоит избегать (например, использовать ООП), но кроме этого global нужен только там, где вы собираетесь перезаписать глобальную переменную (записать новый объект в нее), а не там, где вы ее просто читаете или модифицируете внутреннее состояние объекта. Например, в такой функции:
async def btn_click_start():
    global main
    global btn_start
    btn_start.state(['disabled'])
    ws_main = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(main(),)).start()

global не нужны вообще:

main не перезаписывается новым значением, а просто вызывается как функция
btn_start не перезаписывается новым значением, просто вызывается метод объекта.

В этой функции:
async def btn_click_close():
    global client
    if client:
        await on_close_orders()

переменная client также не перезаписывается, а проверяется ее значение, поэтому global client не нужно.
Но при этом у переменной client у вас только два состояния - либо она уже инициализирована, либо не существует. Если переменная еще не существует, то проверка if client вызовет ошибку NameError. Чтобы такая ошибка не произошла, и проверка работала, нужно заранее (на внешнем уровне, снаружи всех функций) в переменную записать None.

Спасибо большое, поправил по указанным замечаниям - все работает thumbs up

@VictorPankov если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа
